# Relocating initalization psects in MPLABX with XC8 compiler

Tags: pic, mplab, xc8

I'm developing a bootloader (in C, with a few asm statements thanks to the inline assembly) for a PIC16F876, using MPLABXv5.15 as an IDE and XC8v2.10 as a compiler.

I need the bootloader code to be placed at the end, except for its reset vector, which remains in the 4 first instructions.
In order to prevent the linker from placing code at the beginning, I added the *default,-4-FFF* option in the ROM ranges field (*Project Properties > XC8 Global Options > XC8 Linker > Memory model > ROM ranges*) which results in the additional option *-mrom=default,-4-FFF* and works well so far...

Except for 3 instruction words which are placed in the end_init psect which is itself located at 0x4. By diving into the generated .map file, I located the issue within the generated linking command:

```
-W-3 --edf=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc8\v2.10\pic\dat\en_msgs.txt \   
-cs -h+dist/default/production\PJP_BLDR.X.production.sym \   
--cmf=dist/default/production\PJP_BLDR.X.production.cmf -z -Q16F76 \   
-oC:\Users\ALLART~1\AppData\Local\Temp\sj40.2 --defsym=__MPLAB_BUILD=1 \   
-Mdist/default/production/PJP_BLDR.X.production.map -E1 -ver=XC8 \
--acfsm=1493 -ASTACK=0110h-016Fh -pstack=STACK -p_entryTrap_text=FFFh \   
-ACODE=00h-03h,01000h-017FFhx2 -ASTRCODE=00h-03h,01000h-01FFFh \  
-ASTRING=00h-03h,01000h-010FFhx16 -ACONST=00h-03h,01000h-010FFhx16 \   
-AENTRY=00h-03h,01000h-010FFhx16 -ACOMMON=070h-07Fh -ABANK0=020h-06Fh \   
-ABANK1=0A0h-0EFh -ABANK2=0110h-016Fh -ABANK3=0190h-01EFh \  
-ARAM=020h-06Fh,0A0h-0EFh,0110h-016Fh,0190h-01EFh \   
-AABS1=020h-07Fh,0A0h-0EFh,0110h-016Fh,0190h-01EFh -ASFR0=00h-01Fh \   
-ASFR1=080h-09Fh -ASFR2=0100h-010Fh -ASFR3=0180h-018Fh \   
-preset_vec=00h,intentry=04h,init,end_init -ppowerup=CODE -pcinit=CODE \   
-pfunctab=ENTRY -ACONFIG=02007h-02007h -pconfig=CONFIG -DCONFIG=2 \   
-AIDLOC=02000h-02003h -pidloc=IDLOC -DIDLOC=2 -DCODE=2 -DSTRCODE=2 \   
-DSTRING=2 -DCONST=2 -DENTRY=2 -k dist/default/production\startup.o \
dist/default/production\PJP_BLDR.X.production.o
```

Where you can find the following argument:

```
-preset_vec=00h,intentry=04h,init,end_init
```

Meaning that, according to XC8 manual ([here](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/50002053g.pdf)), the ISR, if present, will be placed at 0x4 (as this is the interrupt vector), and the init and end_init psects will be placed right after it (see **section 7.2.18** of the manual), no matter the ROM ranges specified before, as it is indicated that psect placed explicitly have priority over ROM ranges (see **section 4.8.53** of the manual). So far so good, everything's logical and I only need to find a way to change that! It turns out that there is one! Brilliant!

As stated in XC8 Manual (see **section 4.8.6** of the manual which details EXACTLY my issue), I only need to specify *-L-pend_init=* in the extra linker options (*Project Properties > XC8 Global Options > XC8 Linker > Additional options > Extra linker options*) (see **section 4.9.3.4** of the manual).

And here comes the problem. Whatever I do, nothing changes. The linker command in the .map file stays the same, and this end_init psect stays located at 0x4, no matter what.
The command passed to the linker is the following:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc8\v2.10\bin\xc8-cc.exe"  -mcpu=16F76 -Wl,-Map=dist/default/production/PJP_BLDR.X.production.map  -DXPRJ_default=default  -Wl,--defsym=__MPLAB_BUILD=1  -fno-short-double -fno-short-float -mrom=default,-4-FFF -O0 -fasmfile -maddrqual=ignore -xassembler-with-cpp -I"./inc" -mext=cci -Wa,-a -msummary=+psect,+class,+mem,+hex,-file -L-pend_init=200h  -ginhx032 -Wl,--data-init -mkeep-startup -mno-osccal -mno-resetbits -mno-save-resetbits -mdownload -mno-stackcall -std=c99 -gdwarf-3 -mstack=compiled:auto:auto      -Wl,--memorysummary,dist/default/production/memoryfile.xml -o dist/default/production/PJP_BLDR.X.production.elf  build/default/production/src/main.p1 build/default/production/src/serial.p1 build/default/production/src/nsp.p1 build/default/production/src/rs485slave.p1 build/default/production/src/slip.p1
```

So it seems that the linker receives this extra command well. However the .map file isn't modified, so I don't understand well how it should proceed. But it's the way to go according to the manual.
You can notice that the extra command passed to the linker is *-L-pend_init=200h* because out of despair, I just tried a lot of combinations, even placing those arguments in a CODE class, and placing the extra command in the Additional options field in the XC8 Global options, XC8 Linker options and XC8 Compiler options sub-menus. Nothing worked...

I've found this thread, but it doesn't help me ([here](https://www.microchip.com/forums/m679765.aspx)).

I would have posted a message on Microchip forums, but it's been 3 hours and they haven't approved my registration yet (no offense meant, I simply want to post before stopping today's work ;) )

Thanks to everyone who is going to read until the end ! 
Thanks by advance and have a nice day !

PS: I know that you may notice that the the command transmitted to the linker specifies *-mcpu=16F76* and that I said PIC16F876 (and that 16F76 doesn't allow for boatloader, since it cannot modify it's own flash) but that's the only device I have at home, and I'm only experimenting with placing code wherever I want. I don't think it's related to my problem at all.

PPS: Seems that I cannot say hello, everytime I edit this post to add it at the beginning, nothing happens... Sorry for not saying hello right at the beginning then ;)

Edit 1: It seems it's a bug within xc8 suite (I don't know if it comes from the Hlink linker, or from xc8 driver itself). I tried with xc8v1.45 and it works as expected.